# What is the Java equivalent for ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: java, asp.net-membership

Is there a Java equivalent for ASP.NET Membership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though is not **exactly equivalent**, you can take a look at [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) (every **Java EE** application server must support it). It will provide you user/role authentication and authorization.

There is no built-in frontend for managing user and roles though...